# upgraded php to 5.3.19 and memcached stopped working

Tags: php, centos, memcached

I have a server with centos 6.3 and cPanel

After the upgrade from php 5.3.16 to php 5.3.19 my site stopped working.
When I try to execute an `index.php` manually, I'm receiving the following error.

> php: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcached.so: undefined symbol: memcached_last_error_errno

Reinstalled memcached and memcache via `pecl` and manually but that did not help.

What is causing this problem and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Memcached 2.x extension in PHP requires a newer version of `libmemcached`.

So you need to make sure you remove the old one from the system:

```
yum remove libmemcached
```

Be sure it removed `libmemcached.so.2*` from your system.

Download & compile newer libmemcached from https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/+download (for me libmemcached-1.0.13 compiles fine on Centos 6.3)

Recompile memcached extension by issuing:

```
pecl install -f memcached
```

Now it should be fine.
For me it was.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the "extension=memcached.so" extension entry in new php.ini file. Make sure it is there.

Now run "updatedb && locate memcached.so" to find this module and copy it to /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/ location.

Comment: His issue isn't about PHP not being able to find the extension; there are symbols that are not resolving in the SO file, presumably because he's got an old memcache library than what is required from the PHP extension.